# In function 'main': undefined reference to `SDL_Init'

Tags: c, cmake, sdl

I am trying to use SDL2 on Windows. I got the mingW library files from the SDL github and copied the files into my MinGW folder. But whenever I try to compile I get the following console output:

### Console Output

```
====================[ Build | Client | Debug]==================================
C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\231.9011.31\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe --build "D:\Development\Game Development\KongJr\cmake-build-debug" --target Client -j 10
[1/1] Linking C executable Client.exe
FAILED: Client.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -g -Wl,--undefined=_WinMain@16 CMakeFiles/Client.dir/src/main.c.obj CMakeFiles/Client.dir/src/client.c.obj -o Client.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libClient.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  C:/MinGW/lib/libSDL2main.a  C:/MinGW/lib/libSDL2.dll.a  -lws2_32  -lSDL2main  -lSDL2  -lSDL2  -lSDL2main  -mwindows  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cmd.exe /C "cd /D "D:\Development\Game Development\KongJr\cmake-build-debug" && C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file C:/Users/andre/.clion-vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1 -targetBinary "D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/cmake-build-debug/Client.exe" -installedDir C:/Users/andre/.clion-vcpkg/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin -OutVariable out""
CMakeFiles/Client.dir/src/main.c.obj: In function `main':
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:13: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:14: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:16: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:19: undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:21: undefined reference to `SDL_GetWindowSurface'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:22: undefined reference to `SDL_MapRGB'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:22: undefined reference to `SDL_FillRect'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:23: undefined reference to `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:24: undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:28: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
D:/Development/Game Development/KongJr/src/main.c:29: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am using Cmake to link the libraries to my project, so this is what my CMake currently looks like:

### CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(client C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 23)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})


set(SOURCES src/main.c src/client.c include/client.h src/client.h)
add_executable(Client ${SOURCES})

# Link with the Winsock library (ws2_32)
target_link_libraries(Client ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ws2_32 SDL2main SDL2  -lSDL2 -lSDL2main)
```

I get no errors with Cmake whatsoever.

This is the main.c

### main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    } (...)
}
```

Comment: Make sure the libraries you download are of the same variety (32 or 64 bit) as your compiler's default.

Comment: Yes! I am using the x86_64-w64-mingw32 version of the libraries

Comment: Don't really know what's going on but try using the `nm` tool or probably some Windows tool to dump the symbols from your main.obj and from linSDL2.dll.a, and compare.

Comment: I tried, but none of that worked... I think I've gotta switch to Linux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsdl%5D+undefined+reference+SDL_init

Answer (score 0):

I actually used SDL from a package manager, specifically `vcpkg`, rather than using the files for the MinGW compiler from SDL's github because I had trouble getting the MinGW version of SDL to work on my machine, even after trying to uninstall and reinstall the compiler and libraries.

What ended up working for me was installing the libraries using VCPkg and adding them to CMake, and compiling using the bundled compiler of my IDE, in this case CLion. I didn't use the compiler I had previously installed with all the SDL dependencies.